# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp panel on Ubuntu 18.04 does not work

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to start the GUI from xampp on Ubuntu and does not work.
I am using: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp panel` which is supposed to bring up the panel but nothing happens and no error message is displayed either.
Ubuntu version:  18.04 
xampp 7.3.7 
Any idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: if you use 32 system :
`sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run`
if you use 64 system:
`sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run`
The Question is already asked here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/529500/how-to-start-xampp-gui

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

Found on:

https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html

Comment: I cant' find this file, what should I do? sudo /opt/lampp/lampp panel still doesn't work... I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 though/

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** at first, open up the terminal and type the following to see if the folder exists or not.

```
    cd /opt/lampp
```

**Step 2:** if exists, then type ls to see the lists of files and folders

```
    ls
```

**Step 3:** look for a file `manager-linux.run` (or `manager-linux-x64.run`) in the terminal.

**Step 4:** type

```
 chmod +x xampp-linux.run
```

(if the    file name is `manager-linux.run`
otherwise type: `manager-linux-x64.run` as the file name suggests) to make the file executable.

**Step 5:** execute the file as a superuser.

```
 sudo ./manager-linux.run
```